Trouble adding markers to SVG map
so the basic idea is:
a map of the world with markers showing some locations.
this is my first time trying anything with SVG and im having trouble getting the markers to work. i tried to follow the answer to this post, but it doesnt seem to be working for me. i tried to find how to add markers to SVG maps in general, but i couldnt find any easy-to-follow guide.
basically, i tried to make a marker with <symbol>:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created for MapSVG plugin: http://mapsvg.com -->
<svg>
    <symbol id="markerIcon" viewBox="6 6 354 546" >
      <path d="M182.9,551.7c0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.2,0.3S358.3,283,358.3,194.6c0-130.1-88.8-186.7-175.4-186.9
        C96.3,7.9,7.5,64.5,7.5,194.6c0,88.4,175.3,357.4,175.3,357.4S182.9,551.7,182.9,551.7z M122.2,187.2c0-33.6,27.2-60.8,60.8-60.8
        c33.6,0,60.8,27.2,60.8,60.8S216.5,248,182.9,248C149.4,248,122.2,220.8,122.2,187.2z"/>
    </symbol>

but it looks like this when opened:
https://imgur.com/JCn5Iaw
and like this when summoned with <object>
https://imgur.com/WklJ0FZ
the map is too big to include inline here (its 1.18 mb), so heres a link to it hosted on filegarden: https://file.garden/ZqzaaX6Iv3i3b03H/webring-map.svg
thanks in advance.

<svg - did you really neglect to finish this tag with a >, or was that just carelessness while you posted the example?

Typo: you have the  inside the svg oppening tag.

you don't seem to be setting a valid mime-type, so how are you serving the SVG file?

In the SVG you linked to, the <symbol> tag is in the wrong place. It is placed within the opening <svg> tag, which is incorrect.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created for MapSVG plugin: http://mapsvg.com -->
<svg
    <symbol id="markerIcon" viewBox="6 6 354 546" >
      <path d="M182.9,551.7c0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.2,0.3S358.3,283,358.3,194.6c0-130.1-88.8-186.7-175.4-186.9
        C96.3,7.9,7.5,64.5,7.5,194.6c0,88.4,175.3,357.4,175.3,357.4S182.9,551.7,182.9,551.7z M122.2,187.2c0-33.6,27.2-60.8,60.8-60.8
        c33.6,0,60.8,27.2,60.8,60.8S216.5,248,182.9,248C149.4,248,122.2,220.8,122.2,187.2z"/>
    </symbol>


   xmlns:mapsvg="http://mapsvg.com"
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   mapsvg:geoViewBox="-169.110266 83.600842 190.486279 -58.508473"
   width="1009.6727"
   height="665.96301">

The correct location for the <symbol> tag is between the <svg> opening and closing tags.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg width="1009.6727" height="665.96301" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <symbol id="markerIcon" viewBox="6 6 354 546">
    <path style="fill: #f00;" d="M182.9,551.7c0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.2,0.3S358.3,283,358.3,194.6c0-130.1-88.8-186.7-175.4-186.9 C96.3,7.9,7.5,64.5,7.5,194.6c0,88.4,175.3,357.4,175.3,357.4S182.9,551.7,182.9,551.7z M122.2,187.2c0-33.6,27.2-60.8,60.8-60.8 c33.6,0,60.8,27.2,60.8,60.8S216.5,248,182.9,248C149.4,248,122.2,220.8,122.2,187.2z"/>
  </symbol>
  ...
  <use width="35" height="54" transform="matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 609, 166)" href="#markerIcon"/>
</svg>

Here is a working version of your SVG.
